# I don't understand the meaning of "trace" in this context

Tags: general-topology, notation, terminology

I'm not a native English speaker and I found in an old book I'm using for research the word "trace" as it follows:

[image]

It appears several times in the book, but when I look for its meaning on the Internet, I only found it referred to the trace of a matrix.

Can anyone explain what does it mean?

Comment: I believe this is defined in Bourbaki's chapters on set theory in a more general setting. Use the index to find definitions.  I see from the typeface and terminology that you're using Bourbaki: for topology, the set theory chapters are assumed to be known.

Comment: It is Bourbaki indeed. But it happens that I only have the topology one. And of course I tried to find the definition in the book itself, but it isn't there. That's why I asked. But I really didn't think of looking on his other books.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trace of a family $\mathscr F$ of subsets of a set $X$ on a subset $A$ is the family$$\{F\cap A\,|\,F\in\mathscr{F}\}.$$

Comment: This is new to me as well as for the OP. Thank you for informing.